# Block URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to block an URL ended with 'select-a-plan.html' by htaccess?
I tried

`RewriteRule ^/select-a-plan.html$ - [F]`

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/select-a-plan.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule select-a-plan\.html/?$ - [NC,F]
```

***Fixes in OP's nice attempts:***

1. First thing first when using match with RewriteRule it never starts from `/` to your regex `^/` will not match here.
2. I have used `NC` FLAG of apache to enable ignorecase for matching any case file name.
3. Also since string `select-a-plan.html` will be at last of the uri so we need not to use `^`(caret) at first place because it assumes we are matching it from starting of uri.